# no arp entries for vnet

Tags: linux, kvm, bridge, arp

I have multiple kvm hypervisors (HV) which runs bunch of virtual machines (VM).
Every HV has `br0` and every VM is attached to it with its `vnet` interface.

I noticed that one HV at `arp -a` shows me 2 entries per VM:

```
foo (10.1.1.69) at 52:54:00:zz:yy:xx [ether] on vnet3
foo (10.1.1.69) at 52:54:00:zz:yy:xx [ether] on br0
```

But others don't (only entry for `br0` is present).

I compared `sysctl` settings but I found nothing there (especially `net.ipv4.conf.br0.proxy_arp` are set to `1` on all of them)

Kernels are vary:

```
3.16.0-4-amd64 - the one that shows 2 entries
3.2.0-4-amd64 - those that shows only for br0
```

Any ideas ? What else I can check ?

**UPDATE:**

```
# ifconfig vnet3
vnet3     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:zz:yy:xx
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1458  Metric:1
          RX packets:19471686 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47092395 errors:0 dropped:64950 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:2303683173 (2.1 GiB)  TX bytes:62171368865 (57.9 GiB)
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `brctl show br0` for each br0?

Comment: nothing vary there - `STP enabled` (as some are connected with GRE), all has `vnet`'s interfaces in it (which correspond to locally run VM's)

Comment: The vnet interfaces are all without IP address?

Comment: yes, without (at `ip addr` as well)

Comment: Then vnet3 shouldn't appear in the arp-table. `ifconfig vnet3` shows what?

Comment: I put UPDATE to the question with the output. Nothing different than on other HV's here as well. That `vnet3` is just an example. All `vnet`'s on that HV has 2 arp entries (for `br0` and `vnet`) and only one on other (`br0`).